# Create file in DCIM directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a file in the DCIM directory.
I've tried a few variants but I'm not getting the file into the directory.

NSSearchPathDirectory does not work, so what am I doing something wrong?

I do not get out as the path is the directory.

Can anyone give an indication on how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't, because every iOS app is [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)

Comment: How can the camera app save the photos?

Comment: the camera app is made by apple, so is a more important "cityzen".. shortly they use api that are not public..

Comment: how can I export a file and then see it in the folder?
there is a Synchronized folder where I can put the file?

Comment: I guess that the file you want to "export" is an image right? As stated above you have NO ACCESS to that folder, what you can do is to save an image in the user camera roll.

Comment: I want to export any file that I create in my app eg test.dat
I want to be able to read this on a Windows PC since I can only access the DCIM folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Basic example:

```
UIImage *image = ...
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( image, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```