# UUImage imageWithContentsOfFile is nill

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to load a picture from Media/DCIM folder in iOS 8 in order to compress them on the fly later on, so I started writing this script.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {

    NSString *str = @"Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1022.JPG";

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:str];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"File not found at given path");
    }
    else 
    {  
        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:nil];
        //UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:str];
        CIImage *cim = [image CIImage];  

        if (cim == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"File found at given path, but failing to allocate it as an UUImage obj");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"All good !");
            [image release];
        }                                                                                                                         
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output gives "File found at given path, but failing to allocate it as a UUImage obj."

Any ideas why the file is found, but impossible to load it as a UUImage type?
I also tried loading the path as NSBundle, but still, no lucks.

Thanks a lot in advance

FIXED: Answer in the comments of the nicolas's answer

Comment: As a debug step, see if you can get NSData with contents of the file, and then see if you can get UIImage imageWithData:  if you don't get data, then we're having a problem reading the file, if you get data but no image, then the issue must be that the contents of the file don't form a valid image (the work you've done so far provides evidence for the latter)

Comment: Thanks danh for your answer, i tried loading it in NSData and then did a [UIImage imageWithData:imageData], but still failing. I don't think its not a valid image as its picture from the camera roll, i never edited them, they are created by the iphone itself. If i dowload them directly via ssh, i can open them withtout any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can't access the `Media/DCIM` folder in iOS because the system is sandboxed. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4), your app can read and write files directly only on these subfolders of your application folder:

- `Documents/`
- `Documents/Inbox/`
- `Library/`
- `tmp/`

For other purposes like photos, videos and songs picking you need to use the designated pickers of iOS.

Since you need to pick an image from the camera roll, you should use an [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) object instead. It returns the proper `UIImage` for the picture chosen in the picker controller.

Take a look to [this article](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/) from NSHipster for more information about `NSFileManager`. Also read the content of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794636/create-file-in-dcim-directory).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, im root on my iPhone, and this script (theos) is not an app, but a objective-c program that run as a daemon, in background, no UI, so my guess is that as root, i have no limitation whatsoever, i'm giving a path i do have access to, NSFileManager confirm it, so i should be able to load it , no? I have severals program like this that run as daemon, and i never had problem writing files in any kind of directory when i'm running them as root (via sudo)

Comment: I tried putting the picture inside the Documents folder of the mobile user (/var/mobile/Documents) which i should have access to, and the very same is happening, NSFileManager find the file, but can't alloc it as UUImage :/

Comment: Ok, I understand your situation, I though that it was a normal app. Since the path of an app is `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/(Application UUID)`, did you tried to add `/var/mobile/` before `Media/DCIM/...` ? Maybe it could work, maybe not...

Comment: Thanks nicolas for your suggestion, so basically it was a good idea to try the full path instead of the relative path, but it still didn't worked, so instead of converting it to CIImage, i directly did if(image == nil) and it worked perfectly, now with UIImageJPEGRepresentation i can compress them all on the fly, it works wonderfull, thanks for your help and your last suggestion,  thanks a lot !! :)